# code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/", trying to upload my project on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

So, I have successfully uploaded my whole project(angular + node files) on heroku, I have also uploaded my mongodb database on mlab. But my app always gets crashed.

Here is the heroku log:

[image]

I have already tried changing ports to--> log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"), router)), it seems to work for most of them but not for me.
I have also removed engine section from package.json. Still no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You are launching a live development server on heroku on port 4200. I think you should prepare your app for a production build or auto build on heroku. I don't know if you have seen this post https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

Comment: Coming back to this after 1 year, I realize how noob I was, LOL. I was a beginner back then and didn't even specify env port.

Comment: Good shot ! Happens to the best :)